# Current folder on remote folder in Emacs shell is gibberish

Tags: shell, emacs, tramp

When I connect to remote machine with Emacs (using tramp) and then open shell, Emacs opens the shell on the remote machine and I instead of `pwd` I get a bunch of numbers and strings.

How can I fix this?

I'm using Emacs 23.3.1 on Fedora 16

This is what I get:

```
///daae5ccda2e0917c98e90cda7ff909aa#$
```

When I'm on a folder named

```
code/mem/MC/src/
```

on the remote machine.

Comment: Which shell are you running on the remote machine? You may have something in your shell startup scripts which Emacs doesn't like.

Comment: sh. When I try this from arch it work fine though.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Tramp Remote shell Setup](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Remote-shell-setup):

**Interactive shell prompt**

`TRAMP` redefines the shell prompt in order to parse the shell's output robustly. When calling an interactive shell by M-x shell, this doesn't look nice.